# What type are the screw needed to fix PCI boards?

Tags: computer-building, pci

I miss screws to fix a PCI board in my PC, however I can't find out what type of screw it is. Any hints?

Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Computer case screws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws), it is a 6-32 ([UTS](http://www.emachineshop.com/machine-shop/Unified-Thread-Standard/page523.html)) and 0.25 Inches long (only the threaded part is measured). They often have a hexagon head and typically accept #2 size Phillips screwdriver.

[Example](http://www.startech.com/item-specs/PCSCREWKITMC-Assortment-of-11-Common-PC-Screws-and-Jumpers.aspx) of a screw assortment of suitable screws. Better hardware and DIY centres *may* also carry them. A local PC retailer may give you a single one if you are ask nicely.

Note: 6-32 is a US-style screw sizing, so it may not be as readily available from hardware stores in Europe. Don't try to force a M3 screw as a poor substitution, the thread pitch is wrong.

Comment: also a `5.50 x 60mm` nut driver should work.

Answer (score 6):

Something like [these](http://www.nierle3.com/en/article/3447/Screw_Kit_for_PC,_124_pcs..html). The third in the picture is used to fix your PCI slot

[image]

Comment: 2nd and 3rd and 4th top row are the wrong way round. and 2nd from left bottom row is really a standoff

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives to trying to get the correct screw specification.

When you buy a case, you typically get WAY too many of a large assortment of fasteners. Therefore, anyone in your area who deals in computers (almost in any capacity) will have more of them than they know what to do with.

You can also often scrounge one or two from your existing case from a less vital location as a temporary measure.

If you are absolutely "in the middle of nowhere", you can ask someone to send you some - surely someone can pop a few into an envelope for just a few pennies - postage will, no doubt, cost more than the value of the screws.